# solution for 'For input string: "0x100" ' make bash command 'reset' fail to work

Tags: bash, scala, ubuntu, apache-flink

When I start a Scala shell with the following command:

```
start-scala-shell.sh local
```

```
[ERROR] Failed to construct terminal; falling back to unsupported
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x100"
```

Other questions and GitHub suggest that the solution is:

```sh
export TERM=xterm-color
```

However, this solution **disables the `sh` (default shell language of Ubuntu) command `reset`**. After I set `export TERM=xterm-color` in ~/.bashrc or /etc/profile and source the file, then I type `reset`, the command `reset` will fail to reset Terminal.

So, what's the perfect solution to solve this problem while keeping the command `reset` working?

##########################################################################

PS:

①**What's the TERM value before you change it？**

I uncomment `export TERM` in `~/.bashrc` and

export $TERM

bash: export: 「xterm-256color」not a valid identifier

my ~/.bashrc is:
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/zzSSxXmwhD/
(there's something about `term` in front part of this file,which is produced by Ubuntu ,I don't understand it)

②**And how was Scala loaded to you computer?**

It is started by a software called flink.
the flink start script is:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PwsVFh3WvQ/

③**Where is that start script located?**

I have looked the script in②，

but my bash shell is not strong....sorry that I can not locate it....

Comment: today i have learned the difference between reset and clear

Comment: Thanks for your replies，then。。。what's the solution keep `reset` working?

Comment: It would appear that the terminal emulator you're running is not `xterm-color` compatible. What's the `TERM` value before you change it? And how was Scala loaded to you computer? Where is that start script located?

Comment: @jwvh  I have updated it for your comment,could you have a look at it again in `PS`?Thanks for your help~!!

Comment: You would be well served to learn a little more about your own computer system so that you can ask questions that others understand, and answer their questions intelligently. It appears that the script you're trying to run is part of an apache-flink package. Wouldn't it be a good idea to add the flink tag to your question so that flink users can try to help you? Alas, I'm not one of them.